# How do I display Flexslider ONLY if there's at least 1 slide?

Tags: flexslider

I'm using a CMS and have Flexslider integrated, but I'm running into an issue that if there's no slides for a particular event that it displays an empty Flexslider container. What would the function look like that would check to if there was at least one slide and if not that it would not initialize Flexslider? Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the slides images/content from a MySQL database?

If so, the function could look like this:

```
// load slides from database
$get_slides = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM slides WHERE event='$event_Id'");
$count_slides = mysql_num_rows($get_slides);

// Check if any slides exist for particular event
if($count_slides > 0) {
    echo '<div id="slider" class="flexslider">'."\n";
    echo '<ul class="slides">'."\n";
    while($slides = mysql_fetch_array($get_slides)) {

        $image = $slides['image'];
        echo '<li style="background: url('.$image.');">'."\n";

    }
    echo '</ul>'."\n";
    echo '</div>'."\n";

}
```

In this example above, it checks if there is any slides saved in the 'slides' table. The **slide** table could look like this:

```
ID |        image         |   event_Id
 1 |  images/slide1.png   |      2
```

When you open the event site, it check which event  it's all about. How you are doing this is up to you. What really matters, is that you must have the particular event ID. I would receive the event ID from the URL *(http://domain.com/event.php?id=2)*.

Now we know what event to load our slides from. In this example it is `event_Id = 2`.
To answer your question, we only want to show the slider if there is any slides for our event.

We are doing this my counting the rows where the event_Id is equal 2.

If slides are over 0 load the slides, else do nothing.

---

If I'm totally wrong at your question, please let me know.